# Django Practice to organize views that have same permission

Tags: python, django, permissions

The `login_required`, `user_passes_test` and `permission_required` decorator only apply to specific functions, similar for the mixin. But is it a good practice to put `@permission_required('polls.add_choice')` to each and every view that require such permission?

I think it is quite common that multiple views have the same permission. For example, you have an employer and job seeker, only the employer can add company name/ address, post a job and check job application. It is also common that the website requires login for most of its pages.

So my question is what is the idioms/practice assigning the same permission to multiple views? The only recipe I can find is [Beginning Django - Listing 10-8. Permission checks in urls. Pay for include () definitions](https://www.webforefront.com/django/permissionchecks.html#listing-10-6). Another approach is to swap the view function inside a class (as static method) and do some trick the add permission to all methods.

Is there any better sulotion? Or any reason not to do that?

Comment: Consider djangorestframework

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case it is most ideal to use Django's groups system.
It's totally ok to use same permission for several views because in some cases there is more views than the 4 CRUD views and 2 views can be intended to same user/rule/groups.

Comment: Thanks MajoRoth, agree with you. I am just thinking whether is it a good practice(and how) to declare permission, let say login require, for whole module, and additionally delete_permission to some view.

Then all view within module require login, and some special view further require delete_permission. By doing that, it can save a lot of `@login_required`.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on number of online users of your site.
It there are thousands of users online - try to cache that wrappers.
or rewrite all to api